# Unix Domain Sockets datagram client with receive only

Tags: sockets, unix, dns

I have a simulator application which Unix Domain datagram sockets, which sends data to socket path for.ex /var/lib/XYZ.
 sendto is returning -2 which is due to other end no peer is there(no other unix domian socket application is running)

I would like to write a datagram client/peer application using Unix Domain Sockets for receiving data from the server/simulator(which is sending data to /var/lib/XYZ).

My code is as follows:

```
#define BUF_SIZE 1024

#define SV_SOCK_PATH "/var/lib/XYZ"
#define SV_SOCK_PATH2 "/var/lib/ABC"
```

creation of Unix Domain sockets as below:

```
    struct sockaddr_un svaddr, claddr;
    ....      

    sfd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sfd == -1)
        printf("socket creation failed");

    memset(&claddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    claddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;

    strncpy(claddr.sun_path, SV_SOCK_PATH2, sizeof(claddr.sun_path) - 1);

    if (bind(sfd, (struct sockaddr *) &claddr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)) == -1)
        printf("bind failed");

    /* Construct address of server */

    memset(&svaddr, 0, sizeof(struct sockaddr_un));
    svaddr.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy(svaddr.sun_path, SV_SOCK_PATH, sizeof(svaddr.sun_path) - 1);



    while(1)
    {
     int len=sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
     numBytes = recvfrom(sfd, resp, BUF_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr*)&svaddr,&len);
     if (numBytes == -1)
            printf("recvfrom error");
        else{
        printf("no of bytes received from server: %d",(int)numBytes);
        printf("Response %d: %s\n", (int) numBytes, resp);
       }


    }


    remove(claddr.sun_path);            
    //exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

but the program is not receiving anything...is there anything missed out??

Comment: Is anybody sending anything?

Comment: Yes there is simulator which sends to data to socket path /var/lib/XYZ. No other peer is running at the other end thats reason simulator sendto is returning with -2. I just want to create an application to receive that data.

Comment: `sendto()` doesn't return -2. It returns -1 on an error, or a non-negative byte count.

Comment: then what does this mean if it returns -2???

Comment: Well certainly an error. What was the value of `errno`, or better still what did `perror()` print?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to datagrams, there is no real client or server. Either side attempting to send is responsible for addressing datagrams to the other. So, in your code, the setup is all wrong. You're apparently attempting to direct the "server" (but really not a server, just the other peer) to send to you via `svaddr` but that isn't how it works.

For a datagram `AF_UNIX` socket, the sender either needs to explicitly specify the receiver's address in a `sendto` call, or it needs to first `connect` its socket to the receiver's address. (In the latter case, it can then use `send` instead of `sendto` since the peer address has been specified via `connect`.)

You *can't* specify the sending peer's address in the `recvfrom` call. The socket address argument in the `recvfrom` is intended to *return* to you the address from which the datagram was sent. Whatever is in that variable will be overwritten on successful return from `recvfrom`.

One way datagram peer programs are often structured: the "server" creates a well-known path and binds to it, then a "client" creates its own endpoint and binds to *it* (constructing a unique socket address for itself), then the client can `sendto` the server's well-known socket. The server, by using `recvfrom` to obtain the client's address along with the datagram, can then use `sendto` along with the address to return a message to the client (without needing to `connect` its socket). This provides a sort of client-server paradigm on top of the fundamentally equal-peer orientation of the datagram socket.

Finally, I should mention that it's usually a good idea to use fully specified pathnames to ensure both peers are using the same address even if started from different directories. (Normally, with `AF_UNIX`, the address is a path name in the file system used to "rendezvous" between the two peers -- so without a full path "some_socket" is "./some_socket" in the current working directory. Some systems, such as linux, also support an abstract "hidden" namespace that doesn't require a full path, but you must use an initial null byte in the name to specify that.)

Comment: If he wants to filter the input he should use `connect()`.

Comment: I have a simulator application which Unix Domain datagram sockets, which sends data to socket path for.ex /var/lib/XYZ.
 sendto is returning -2 which is due to other end no peer is there(no other unix domian socket application is running)

I would like to write a datagram client/peer application using Unix Domain Sockets for receiving data from the server/simulator(which is sending data to /var/lib/XYZ).

Comment: Then your receiver application should `bind` to `/var/lib/XYZ`. It should then be able to receive those datagrams.

Comment: /var/lib/XYZ is already in use.. which is used by application/simulator which is sending. if i try to bind it "already in use" error is being printed

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. I strongly suspect you are misunderstanding what the simulator is doing. But I see no way to help you without more information.

Comment: @Geeky_Folk Then *it* is bound to that address, and it is sending *from* XYZ *to* some other address, and *that* is what you should be binding to, whatever it is.